# ApiPlatform: How to update instead of create a child entity that is not a @ApiResource nor a @ApiSubresource

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a `ThirdPartyEntity` from a third party bundle that, using a `ThirdPartyEntityTrait`, I link to `MyEntity` in my project.

Now, as the `ThirdPartyEntity` is not set a `ApiResource` nor as an `ApiSubresource` and as I don't have any serializaton group set on `MyEntity`, when I get `MyEntity` from ApiPlatform, it returns me something like this:

```
{
   "@id":"/api/my_entities/17",
   "@type":"MyEntity",
   "id":17,
   "third_party_entity": {
      "id":22,
      "a_property":"some value"
   }
}
```

BUT IF I `PUT` a changed value for `a_property` with this `body`:

```
{
   "@id":"/api/my_entities/17",
   "@type":"MyEntity",
   "id":17,
   "third_party_entity": {
      "id":22,
      "a_property":"some NEW value to update"
   }
}
```

I get a new `third_party_entity` to be created and get this response:

```
{
   "@id":"/api/my_entities/17",
   "@type":"MyEntity",
   "id":17,
   "third_party_entity": {
      "id":23,
      "a_property":"some NEW value to update"
   }
}
```

**SO, HOW CAN I UPDATE `third_party_entity` instead of creating it each time?**

HERE THERE ARE THE INVOLVED CLASSES AND TRAITS

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_my_entities")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ApiResource()
 */
class MyEntity
{
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    // This is the trait I use to link MyEntity
    // with the entity from the third-party bundle
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    use ThirdPartyEntityTrait;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

And this is the `ThirdPartyEntityTrait`:

```
trait ThirdPartyEntityTrait
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Namespace\To\Bundle\Entity\ThirdPartyEntity", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="thirdPartyEntity", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $thirdPartyEntity;

    /**
     * @param thirdPartyEntity $thirdPartyEntity
     *
     * @return ThirdPartyEntity
     */
    public function setThirdPartyEntity(thirdPartyEntity $thirdPartyEntity): ThirdPartyEntity
    {
        $this->thirdPartyEntity = $thirdPartyEntity;

        /** @var ThirdPartyEntity $this */
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return thirdPartyEntity
     */
    public function getThirdPartyEntity(): ?thirdPartyEntity
    {
        return $this->thirdPartyEntity;
    }

    /**
     * @return thirdPartyEntity
     */
    public function removeThirdPartyEntity(): ?thirdPartyEntity
    {
        $thirdPartyEntity = $this->getThirdPartyEntity();

        $this->thirdPartyEntity = null;

        return $thirdPartyEntity;
    }
}
```

As you can see, nothing more a property to save the relation and some accessors methods.

This is, instead, the linked Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="third_party_entities")
 */
class ThirdPartyEntity
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="aProperty", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $aProperty;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAProperty()
    {
        return $this->aProperty;
    }

    public function setAProperty($aProperty)
    {
        $this->aProperty = $aProperty;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

[This question is cross-posted also on GitHub.](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/1950)

Comment: I am having the same issue, I can feel the pain

Comment: I solved it! I'm going to write the answer...

Comment: Answer posted! 

Answer (score 2):

The solution was pretty simple: use another config method!

Practically, it is possible to mix configuration types and so, it is possible to use the annotations along with the yaml configuration.

Given this, it is sufficient to create a new config file in `config/api_platform/third_party_entity.yaml`.

In it put the configuration required to map the entity from the third party bundle:

```
resources:
    App\Entity\MyEntity:
        properties:
            remote:
                subresource:
                    resourceClass: 'Third\Party\Bundle\TheBundle\Entity\ThirdPartyEntity'
    Third\Party\Bundle\TheBundle\Entity\ThirdPartyEntity:
```

This way it is possible to configure as subresource the entity from the third party bundle to which we don't have access with annotations.